# Does the Bugbear’s "Surprise Attack" feature apply on its first round of combat or the players'?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, surprise

The [Bugbear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bugbear)'s Surprise Attack feature reads:

> **Surprise Attack:** If the bugbear surprises a creature and hits it with
>   an attack *during the first round of combat*, the target takes an extra
>   7 (2d6) damage from the attack.

Is it referring to the bugbear's first round of combat or the players'?

My players were clearing Cragmaw Castle in LMoP. They were in a long combat that went from room to room, then entered another room and got surprised by a bugbear. I wasn't sure if this triggered the surprise attack or not...

I assume it doesn't trigger and it's meant as if the Bugbear ambushes an unaware party, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a character be surprised mid-combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/can-a-character-be-surprised-mid-combat)

Comment: Hello.  The title might be more clear if you reworded it to be, "Does the Bugbear’s “Surprise Attack” feature apply on its first round of combat or the encounter?"

Comment: Note that, regardless of the answer, the feature likely does not work in the example provided because the players are not surprised. Personally I would allow it if the players were unaware of the Bugbear when it attacked, but RAW you can only be surprised on your first turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It is the same thing

The bugbear and the players each have a *turn* in the first *round*.

The Order of Combat (PHB p189):

> The game organizes the chaos of combat into a cycle of rounds and turns. A round represents about 6 seconds in the game world.
>   During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn. ...
>   Once everyone has taken a turn, the fight continues to the next round if neither side has defeated the other.

In your example, the bugbear had a turn, either waiting for the party to arrive, or approaching them. If it knows about the combat, he is a part of it, for example its movement should be tracked in turn increments.

Comment: But "During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn." sounds as if the Bugbear is not having a turn, as he is not "participant in a battle" yet?

Comment: @ideamonster it had a turn, either _waiting_ for the party to arrive, or approaching them

Comment: @ideamonster here's a nice answer (to me) to anderstand the meaning of a combat/round/turn : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140614/51851

Comment: @ideamonster: Make sure you understand the mechanics of surprise, and how it occurs within the confines of initiative/rounds.